# Is there any solution to add loginbox in typo3 6.2.31

Tags: typo3

I have installed typo3 6.2.31 which is compatible for php5+ enviornment. Backend and front end is working fine but I am not able to add login functionality. How could we add Login extension in typo3 6.2.31?

Comment: What did you try, what errors are you getting?

Comment: No errors but not able to show login form in frontend. If i add form in front end then how will i done login process using pid? Is there any code or example, it will helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly get a frontend login up and running with the [felogin extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/6.2/) which is bundled with TYPO3.

Notice that you should consider updating to a newer TYPO3 version which still gets security fixes.

Comment: I have read felogin extension document. I have implemented document settings also. but when i go to that page that time login form is not displaying. I have added template to that page also.

Comment: If i have written code of login form in template then how will integrate login process?

Comment: There is nothing special about this really. If you have a `username` and `password`, `logintype` (must be `login`) and `pid` field in a form, the login will be triggered if you submit it.